# add two value to combobox

Tags: c#, java, jcombobox

In c# we can add a text and a value to each items of combobox, I want to know is it possible in Java also? if not please advice.

Comment: Pop quiz: what is the code for doing that in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should learn how to use [ComboBox](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) in java.

Comment: Since Jcombobox accept Object can I create a class and just overwrite ToString method?

Answer (score 3):

I Solved my problem by create a class like

```
public class ItemInfo {
    public String Name;
    public String Value;

    public ItemInfo(String Name , String Value) {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Value = Value;
    }

    public String toString() {
      return Name ;
    }

    public String getValue() {
      return Value ;
    }
}
```

than I just create a new object from this class & pass it to my combobox

```
combbox1.addItem(new ItemInfo(item[0],item[1]));
```

job done :)!